# How do I purchase multiple copies of the same item from a vendor?

Tags: path-of-exile

I am trying to upgrade all my orbs.

To save time, I tried to <kbd>Shift</kbd>-click the orb I want to purchase in the vendor's inventory hoping the game would give me the chance to enter the quantity I want to purchase. But alas, that's not the case. I have also tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-click and <kbd>Alt</kbd>-click to no avail.

Does anyone know how to do this or is this possible at all?

Comment: AFAIK, there is currently no quick-buy mechanic available.

Comment: Same here.  I'd add that the game severely lacks of user-friendliness regarding orbs management (auto-stacking, quick-buy/sell, etc).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Currently players are not able to buy multiple amount of the same item from the vendor at once. Instead you are forced to buy them one by one.

This has been reported as an issue in official forums with a lot of players complaining about it, so it's probably going to change in the future, and once it does i will update my answer.

As of *Version 0.10.2b* you can now use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + Click to buy items from vendors.

Comment: Well I will keep an eye on this question and as soon as this user-unfriendly feature changes, I will update it.

Comment: @deutschZuid Now is the time for a updated answer, you can now ctrl + click to spam click purchasing

Comment: @Cresh Thx for the heads up. I've quit PoE not long after answering this so i wasn't paying attention on new patches anymore.